# Shiny app not deploying "Unhandled Exception: Child Task 713*****"

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that includes a helper.R file and a data.txt file. It seemingly runs fine locally, but when I go to deploy it on shinyapps.io, I get:

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 57723...DONE
Deploying bundle: 250119 for application: 57723 ...
Waiting for task: 71388412
################################ Begin Task Log ################################ 
################################# End Task Log ################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 71388413 error: Unhandled Exception:
```

Each time the task number changes (I've also had 71387628, 71387509, 71386087, 71375249, 713*****). I'm running r version 3.2.1 (World-Famous-Astronaut) on Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit). The data file is 1.1MB, so the file size should not be the issue. The only library I'm using is data.table which is from CRAN.

What might be the issue?

Comment: Mine was working earlier today (~ 4 hours ago) and has suddenly started giving me the exact same error. Even example code will not deploy properly.

Answer (score 4):

It's just that the upload server that got trashed. The Coursera Data Science Capstone was due to day right around that time, so a thousand or so people all flooded it at once, and it went down. No idea when it'll be back up though.

Comment: Up and running again as of ~ 9:30 EST.